# How can I scrape restaurant titles and descriptions if website has load more button?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup and I'm trying to get all restaurant titles and descriptions from the infatuation. This is proving difficult as the website has lots of nested HTML structure as well as a load more button. Here's where I am.

Code:

```
#Request to website and download HTML contents
url='https://www.theinfatuation.com/new-york/reviews'
req=requests.get(url)
content=req.text

string = soup.find_all("h6")
print(string)
```

```
Output: 

[<h6 class="styles_headText__4SYjt">All Reviews</h6>, <h6 class="styles_detailedStoryTitle__e3w46">Musette Wine Bar</h6>, <h6 class="styles_detailedStoryTitle__e3w46">Milady's</h6>, <h6 class="styles_detailedStoryTitle__e3w46">Tradisyon</h6>, <h6 class="styles_detailedStoryTitle__e3w46">Lady Wong</h6>, <h6 class="styles_detailedStoryTitle__e3w46">Mamak’s Corner</h6>, <h6 class="styles_detailedStoryTitle__e3w46">Ashes Burnnit</h6>, <h6 class="styles_detailedStoryTitle__e3w46">Padi D'NYC</h6>, <h6 class="styles_detailedStoryTitle__e3w46">Mr. Fried Rice</h6>, <h6 class="styles_detailedStoryTitle__e3w46">Daisy's Dream</h6>, <h6 class="styles_detailedStoryTitle__e3w46">Hainan Jones</h6>, <h6 class="styles_detailedStoryTitle__e3w46">Marufuku Ramen</h6>, <h6 class="styles_detailedStoryTitle__e3w46">Lillie's Victorian Establishment</h6>, <h6 class="styles_detailedStoryTitle__e3w46">Prince Tea House</h6>, <h6 class="styles_detailedStoryTitle__e3w46">The Russian Tea Room</h6>, <h6 class="styles_detailedStoryTitle__e3w46">Maialino (vicino)</h6>, <h6 class="styles_detailedStoryTitle__e3w46">Zaytinya</h6>, <h6 class="styles_detailedStoryTitle__e3w46">Monkey Bar</h6>, <h6 class="styles_detailedStoryTitle__e3w46">Christos Steakhouse</h6>, <h6 class="styles_detailedStoryTitle__e3w46">Peter Luger Steak House</h6>, <h6 class="styles_detailedStoryTitle__e3w46">Buka</h6>]
```

So, I'm able to extract 21 restaurants titles but I believe the load more button on the page is preventing me from scraping the rest. Any suggestions?

Link to Website [Infatuation](https://www.theinfatuation.com/new-york/reviews)

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably to use the python requests library to request the JSON with the reviews. 
When you click on the button, the website's JavaScript requests JSON that contains all the data for the reviews. This means you can bypass the button by just requesting the JSON with python.
 I just took a quick look at the site you linked. I found this request in the inspector that seems to contain all the review information.
 You can find all the requests in the browser inspector under the network tab.

[image]